# php unable to decode json object

Tags: php

I have this json object that I want to get the access_token but its refusing i have no idea why . This is the response I want the access_token

```
{
        "access_token": "Alhq74lVl5GAOVAZrprOGSS1Gj73",
        "expires_in": "3599"
    }
```

This is the code

```
function generateToke() {
// $url = 'https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials';
   $url = 'https://api.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials';
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $credentials = base64_encode('qniogqzdbIskIQt9nxgxG1wSBkzgUqN0:XUjxWzQY3WTndqHh');
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ' . $credentials)); //setting a custom header
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

   $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
   $result = json_decode($curl_response);


   $token = $result->access_token;
   echo $token;
```

}

getting the same error

the above code is still displaying to me the json but i want to get only the Alhq74lVl5GAOVAZrprOGSS1Gj73

Comment: Change `$token = $result->$access_token;` to `$token = $result->access_token;`

Comment: $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
       $result = json_decode($curl_response);
       $token = $result->access_token;
       echo $token;

Comment: still getting the same

Comment: note: the syntax to acces a dynamic property name is usually with brackets `$token = $result->{$access_token};`. I don't know your php version, it seems to work for you because you don't get undefined or an error, but just in case you want to know

Comment: @Kaddath _note: the syntax to acces a dynamic property name is usually with brackets_ no it is not: [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). It's only nessessary if you use it with arrays (see the referenced documentation).

Comment: BTW: You chould change your credentials now... Never post your real credentials at SO.

Comment: Even after the change, echoing out $token is displayed the FULL JSON return from the curl? How is that possible ;)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/jvkjF

Comment: @JoshuaK that's the reason i used the word usually. Almost always seen it with brackets and i think it helps a lot for readability, with all the PHP mess for object properties, sometimes there's a `$`, sometimes not and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing the `access_token` property of the resulting object, you try to access a property that is named in the not defined variable `$access_token;`.

So just remove the $-sign and it shoudl work:

```
$token = $result->access_token;
```

Furthermore you're missing a curl option to return the content:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Without this option set to true you're not retrieving the response from the `curl_exec` call.

Comment: its saying trying to get non object

Comment: @Eve if you have this error, maybe there was an error decoding the json, you can check if the case by displaying `json_last_error_msg()` just after the decode and see if there's something in it

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$token = $result->$access_token;
```

To (without the `$` on access_token):

```
$token = $result->access_token;
```

It's not working because PHP has a feature called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) which you've accidentally used. PHP is trying to get the property of whatever the value of `$access_token` is. E.g. if a variable called `$access_token` was set to `helloworld`, PHP would run `$result->helloworld` and replace `$access_token` with it's value.